# Filter list that does not have an invalid email and opt-out email using SugarCRM 7 API

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

I want to filter list that does not have an invalid email and opt-out email in Leads and Contact module using SugarCRM 7 API.

I have added below email filter in arguments but does not work. How to email filter via SugarCRM 7.x rest API.

```
$filter_arguments = array(

            "filter" => array(

                array(
                    "assigned_user_id" => 1,
                ),
                array(
                    "email1" => array(
                        array(
                            'opt_out' => array(
                                '$equals' => ''
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ),
        );
$url = $base_url . "/Contacts/filter";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This much code will not help you please check this :

[Reference Link 1](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/03/10/creating-custom-filters-in-sugarcrm-7/)

[Reference Link 2](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Architecture/Filters/)

The following example will demonstrate how to add a predefined filter on the Accounts module to return all records with an account type of "Customer" and industry of "Other".

To create a predefined filter, create a display label extension in  `./custom/Extension/modules/<module>/Ext/Language/`. For this example, we will create:

```
./custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/Language/en_us.filterAccountByTypeAndIndustry.php

<?php

$mod_strings['LBL_FILTER_ACCOUNT_BY_TYPE_AND_INDUSTRY'] = 'Customer/Other Accounts';
```

Next, create a custom filter extension in  `./custom/Extension/modules/<module>/Ext/clients/base/filters/basic/.`

**For this example, we will create:**

```
./custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/clients/base/filters/basic/filterAccountByTypeAndIndustry.php

<?php

$viewdefs['Accounts']['base']['filter']['basic']['filters'][] = array(
    'id' => 'filterAccountByTypeAndIndustry',
    'name' => 'LBL_FILTER_ACCOUNT_BY_TYPE_AND_INDUSTRY',
    'filter_definition' => array(
        array(
            'account_type' => array(
                '$in' => array(
                    'Customer',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'industry' => array(
                '$in' => array(
                    'Other',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'editable' => false,
    'is_template' => false,
);
```

You should notice that the editable and is_template options have been set to "false". If editable is not set to "false", the filter will not be displayed in the list view filter's list.

Finally, navigate to Admin > Repair and click "Quick Repair and Rebuild" to rebuild the extensions and make the predefined filter available for users.
**Adding Initial Filters to Lookup Searches**

To add initial filters to record lookups and type-ahead searches, define a filter template. This will allow you to filter results for users when looking up a parent related record. The following example will demonstrate how to add an initial filter for the Account lookup on the Contacts module. This initial filter will limit records to having an account type of "Customer" and a dynamically assigned user value determined by the contact's assigned user.

To add an initial filter to the Contacts record view, create a display label for the filter in `./custom/Extension/modules/<module>/Ext/Language/. For this example , we will create:`

```
./custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/Language/en_us.filterAccountTemplate.php

<?php

$mod_strings['LBL_FILTER_ACCOUNT_TEMPLATE'] = 'Customer Accounts By A Dynamic User';
```

Next, create a custom template filter extension in  `./custom/Extension/modules/<module>/Ext/clients/base/filters/basic/`.
 For this example, create:

```
./custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/clients/base/filters/basic/filterAccountTemplate.php

<?php

$viewdefs['Accounts']['base']['filter']['basic']['filters'][] = array(
    'id' => 'filterAccountTemplate',
    'name' => 'LBL_FILTER_ACCOUNT_TEMPLATE',
    'filter_definition' => array(
        array(
            'account_type' => array(
                '$in' => array(),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'assigned_user_id' => ''
        )
    ),
    'editable' => true,
    'is_template' => true,
);
```

As you can see, the filter_definition contains arrays for account_type and assigned_user_id. These filter definitions will receive their values from the contact record view's metadata. You should also note that this filter has is_template and editable set to "true". This is required for initial filters.

Once the filter template is in place, modify the contact record view's metadata. To accomplish this, edit ./custom/modules/Contacts/clients/base/views/record/record.php to adjust the account_name field. If this file does not exist in your local Sugar installation, navigate to Admin > Studio > Contacts > Layouts > Record View and click "Save & Deploy" to generate it. In this file, identify the panel_body array as shown below:

```
1 => 
array (
    'name' => 'panel_body',
    'label' => 'LBL_RECORD_BODY',
    'columns' => 2,
    'labelsOnTop' => true,
    'placeholders' => true,
    'newTab' => false,
    'panelDefault' => 'expanded',
    'fields' => 
    array (
        0 => 'title',
        1 => 'phone_mobile',
        2 => 'department',
        3 => 'do_not_call',
        4 => 'account_name',
        5 => 'email',
    ),
),
```

**Next, modify the account_name field to contain the initial filter parameters.**

```
1 =>
array (
    'name' => 'panel_body',
    'label' => 'LBL_RECORD_BODY',
    'columns' => 2,
    'labelsOnTop' => true,
    'placeholders' => true,
    'newTab' => false,
    'panelDefault' => 'expanded',
    'fields' =>
    array (
        0 => 'title',
        1 => 'phone_mobile',
        2 => 'department',
        3 => 'do_not_call',
        4 => array (
            //field name
            'name' => 'account_name',

            //the name of the filter template
            'initial_filter' => 'filterAccountTemplate',

            //the display label for users
            'initial_filter_label' => 'LBL_FILTER_ACCOUNT_TEMPLATE',



     //the hardcoded filters to pass to the templates filter definition
            'filter_populate' => array(
                'account_type' => array('Customer')
            ),

            //the dynamic filters to pass to the templates filter definition
            //please note the index of the array will be for the field the data is being pulled from
            'filter_relate' => array(
                //'field_to_pull_data_from' => 'field_to_populate_data_to'
                'assigned_user_id' => 'assigned_user_id',
            )
        ),
        5 => 'email',
    ),
),
```

Finally, navigate to Admin > Repair and click "Quick Repair and Rebuild". This will rebuild the extensions and make the initial filter available for users when selecting a parent account for a contact.
**Adding Initial Filters to Drawers from a Controller**

When creating your own views, you may need to filter a drawer called from within your custom controller. Using an initial filter, as described in the Adding Initial Filters to Lookup Searches section, we can filter a drawer with predefined values by creating a filter object and populating the config.filter_populate property as shown below:

```
//create filter
var filterOptions = new app.utils.FilterOptions()
    .config({
        'initial_filter': 'filterAccountTemplate',
        'initial_filter_label': 'LBL_FILTER_ACCOUNT_TEMPLATE',
        'filter_populate': {
            'account_type': ['Customer'],
            'assigned_user_id': 'seed_sally_id'
        }
    })
    .format();

//open drawer
app.drawer.open({
    layout: 'selection-list',
    context: {
        module: 'Accounts',
        filterOptions: filterOptions,
        parent: this.context
    }
});
```

To create a filtered drawer with dynamic values, create a filter object and populate the config.filter_relate property using the populateRelate method as shown below:

```
//record to filter related fields by
var contact = app.data.createBean('Contacts', {
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'Smith',       
    'assigned_user_id': 'seed_sally_id'
});

//create filter
var filterOptions = new app.utils.FilterOptions()
    .config({
        'initial_filter': 'filterAccountTemplate',
        'initial_filter_label': 'LBL_FILTER_ACCOUNT_TEMPLATE',
        'filter_populate': {
            'account_type': ['Customer'],
        },
        'filter_relate': {
            'assigned_user_id': 'assigned_user_id'
        }
    })
    .populateRelate(contact)
    .format();

//open drawer
app.drawer.open({
    layout: 'selection-list',
    context: {
        module: 'Accounts',
        filterOptions: filterOptions,
        parent: this.context
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: IF its help you please upvote and accept the answer.